# Euler4 with scala - apparent utf8 in the comment inhibits compilation

Tags: scala, utf-8

I just started fighting my way up the learning curve with Scala.  I generally do this sort of thing by implementing the first twenty or so Euler problems.  Things took a surprising turn when I hit #4.

```
/*
    A palindromic number reads the same both ways. 
    The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.

    Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.
*/

object Four
{
    def main(args: Array[String]) 
    {
        println("start");
        println("end");
    }
}
```

Although it might not jump out at you, the x between 91 and 99 in the comment is actually a unicode x which is encoded as a D7.  If I change that to an ASCII X the program compiles and runs as expected.  If I leave it as is, the program appears to run, but there is no output.

Running from the command line shows

```
c:\projects\Euler>scalac -feature euler4.scala
error: IO error while decoding euler4.scala with UTF-8
Please try specifying another one using the -encoding option
one error found
```

A little bit of research on SO suggests specifying the encoding

```
c:\projects\Euler>scalac -encoding UTF-8 -feature euler4.scala
error: IO error while decoding euler4.scala with UTF-8
Please try specifying another one using the -encoding option
one error found
```

My config is windows 10 with
**"Welcome to Scala 2.12.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_121)."**

Comment: Have you tried looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23224219/does-the-scala-compiler-work-with-utf-8-encoded-source-files ? I tried adding this character to a file (in a commentary, of course) and it didn't break anything.

Comment: Unable to reproduce the problem. (Scala 2.12.1) What version are you running?

Comment: If you are going to tell a program which encoding to use to read your file, you should tell it the encoding that _you used to save the file._ It seems UTF-8 would be a great choice.

Comment: @jwvh Thank you.  I have added that information to the questions.

Comment: @tom.  Yes.  I had assumed that it was straight ASCII.  The comment is a cut and paste from the euler site.   https://projecteuler.net/problem=4.   I am basically using msvc 2015 as the text editor, and have a button that runs scala at the command line and dumps the output into the msvc output window.

Comment: @Cyrille.  Yes.  That like was the source of the suggestion to specify the encoding as utf8.

Comment: Visual Studio picks archaic encodings as the default for some types of files. To fix, File » Save As and drop down the options on the Save button or File » Advanced Save Options.